# PostSharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect Indent/Padding

Tags: c#, nlog, postsharp

I've been trying to add some padding to my own Method Boundary Aspect.

StackTrace seems to be of no help, I cannot find a pattern to calculate the frame count baseline, which for simple scenarios is around 12.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyLogger : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
  public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
  {
    // ...
    var ignoreFrameCount = ???; // in simple scenarios is ~12
    var n = new StackTrace().FrameCount - ignoreFrameCount;
    var padding = String.Empty.PadLeft(n*2);
    // ...
```

I know PostSharp does it ([Indentation in Logging](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Announcing-PostSharp-31-Preview))

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a StackTrace is generally really really slow and I would not certainly recommend it during logging.

The easiest way is to declare:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static int indentLevel;
```

Then, all you need to do is to properly increment and decrement this variable in OnEntry and OnExit advices.

Comment: Works very well. Some code below for those who may like to see the solution integrated to the problem.
`   [ThreadStatic]
    private static int _indentLevel;
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var padding = String.Empty.PadLeft(_indentLevel++*2);
        // ...

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var padding = String.Empty.PadLeft(--_indentLevel*2);
        // ...`